# Meteor._wrapAsync

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor

I wrapped a function `writeTransaction()` with `Meteor._wrapAsync` and called it 5 times in a `for` loop which writes a MySQL transaction.

However from the MySQL query logs, it seems that the next iteration of the loop is executed before the function `writeTransactionSync()` in the previous loop has finished.

If `Meteor._wrapAsync` does not make the function blocking, how can we make the function synchronous?

**Server-side Code**

```
writeTransaction = function(data, callback) {

    var mysql = Meteor.require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(info).connect()


    connection.beginTransaction(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err) {
        connection.query('DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = ?', [data._id], Meteor.bindEnvironment( function(err) {
            connection.commit( Meteor.bindEnvironment( function(err) {

            }))
        }))
    }))

    callback(null)

}


writeTransactionSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(writeTransaction)

for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    writeTransactionSync(data[i])
}
```

**MySQL Query Log**

```
  329 Connect   root@localhost on meteor
  330 Connect   root@localhost on meteor
  331 Connect   root@localhost on meteor
  332 Connect   root@localhost on meteor
  333 Connect   root@localhost on meteor
  329 Query START TRANSACTION
  330 Query START TRANSACTION
  331 Query START TRANSACTION
  332 Query START TRANSACTION
  333 Query START TRANSACTION
  329 Query DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = '34zCYZXBxEkJapkYh'
  330 Query DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = 'SNR8zTEzGCw6X7RZ2'
  331 Query DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = 'TAF2TJkN5LzFRqAnX'
  332 Query DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = '57pJbvFYmHTpM5E6a'
  333 Query DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = 'BtNLGa3gjRGAfmMFf'
  331 Query COMMIT
  332 Query COMMIT
  329 Query COMMIT
  330 Query COMMIT
  333 Query COMMIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Meteor._wrapAsync` is synchronous, provided that you fire the callback after all the tasks are done. It will only block the fiber if it knows the method has completed, so when you call `callback(null)`, it assumes it is complete.

You have used `callback(null)` after you call `connection.query` but it would be called regardless of whether your query has completed or not, and since it takes a bit of time for a query to execute with MySQL, its likely its always complete (and act asynchronous) before the query has actually run.

You should place it inside the callback of the query:

```
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
    connection.query('DELETE FROM orders WHERE _id = ?', [data._id], function(err) {
        connection.commit(function(err) {
            callback(null);
        });
    });
});
```

Also you don't need `Meteor.bindEnvironment` when you use `Meteor._wrapAsync`, especially when you're not using any Meteor code in the functions anywhere (You dont use meteor code in any of your connection callbacks, so its not needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout [this video on Meteor._wrapAsync here in eventedmind](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/meteor-wrapasync).  It did a good job on this topic.